# Failed To Execute Goal Error

Tags: java, maven, ardor3d

I am trying to install Ardor3D (A 3D Java Engine) with Netbeans but I have run into some problems. I successfully downloaded and installed all of the source code and it shows up fine in the IDE, but when I try to run any of the Examples, it comes up with this error:

```
[exec:exec]
Error: Could not find or load main class null
------------------------------------------------------------------------
BUILD FAILURE
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total time: 5:35.229s
Finished at: Mon Jul 29 15:23:20 EDT 2013
Final Memory: 7M/18M
------------------------------------------------------------------------
Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.1.1:exec (default-cli) on project ardor3d-examples: Result of cmd.exe /X /C "java -classpath G:\Files\Java\Projects\Ardor3D\ardor3d-examples\target\classes;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-lwjgl\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-lwjgl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-core\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-core-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-math\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-math-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-savable\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-savable-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\google\guava\guava\14.0.1\guava-14.0.1.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl_util\2.8.4\lwjgl_util-2.8.4.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl\2.8.4\lwjgl-2.8.4.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.8.4\lwjgl-platform-2.8.4-natives-windows.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.8.4\lwjgl-platform-2.8.4-natives-linux.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\lwjgl\lwjgl\lwjgl-platform\2.8.4\lwjg l-platform-2.8.4-natives-osx.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\net\java\jinput\jinput\2.0.5\jinput-2.0.5.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\net\java\jutils\jutils\1.0.0\jutils-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-awt\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-awt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-swt\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-swt-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\eclipse\swt\swt\3650\swt-3650-win32-x86.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-jogl\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-jogl-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt-main\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-main-2.0.2-rc12.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-android-armv6.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-amd64 .jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-armv6.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-i586.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-macosx-universal.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-solaris-amd64.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-solaris-i586.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.0.2-rc12\gluegen-rt-2.0.2-rc12-natives-windows-i586.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jo gamp\jogl\jogl-all-main\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-main-2.0.2-rc12.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-android-armv6.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-amd64.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-armv6.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-linux-i586.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-macosx-universal.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-solaris-amd64.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\ 2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-solaris-i586.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jogamp\jogl\jogl-all\2.0.2-rc12\jogl-all-2.0.2-rc12-natives-windows-i586.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-effects\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-effects-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-extras\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-extras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-collada\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-collada-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-animation\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-animation-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\org\jdom\jdom2\2.0.4\jdom2-2.0.4.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\jaxen\jaxen\1.1.4\jaxen-1.1.4.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-terrain\1.0-SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-terrain-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar;C:\Users\Idrees\.m2\repository\com\ardor3d\ardor3d-ui\1.0 -SNAPSHOT\ardor3d-ui-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar null" execution is: '1'. -> [Help 1]
```

I believe this error is caused by the fact that I am running Ardor on a portable version of Netbeans. It finds the Java classpath fine, but it tries to locate the SNAPSHOT (?) in the computers file's themselves. Does anyone know how to make it download and locate the files in the flashdrive itself? I can assume it can be fixed by redirecting where the IDE looks for the repositories but, due to my lack of knowledge on the subject, I have no idea how to accomplish this. Thanks for your help!

P.S. If you need me to upload Netbeans portable for error correction, just say

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, turns out the answer was actually a problem on my part (mostly stupidity). To fix this, instead of running the example from the example itself, you must use the "Example Runner" (duh). For some reason it does not work otherwise...